# Twitter Widget Anchor Underlines

Tags: html, css, twitter

I'm implementing a Twitter "[Profile Widget](http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile)" on my website, and am having trouble figuring out how to make it accessible to tabbed navigators using the a:focus selector.

My CSS is as follows:

```
    #activity a:link { color:inherit; text-decoration:none; }
    #activity a:visited { color:inherit; text-decoration:none; }
    #activity a:hover { color:inherit; text-decoration:underline; }
    #activity a:active { color:inherit; text-decoration:none; }
    #activity a:focus { color:inherit; text-decoration: underline; outline:none; }
```

The rest of my anchors are underlined correctly, but no such luck for the widget. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: unable to understand your problem. explain more on "make it accessible to tabbed navigators"

Answer (score 1):

You have to override Twitter's styles. Basically, make your selectors carry more weight. The simplest way is just to chain a bunch of id's together:

```
#activity a:link, #wrap #twitter-container #twtr-widget-1 .twtr-tweet a:link { color:inherit; text-decoration:none; }
#activity a:visited, #wrap #twitter-container #twtr-widget-1 .twtr-tweet a:visited { color:inherit; text-decoration:none; }
/* and so on... */
```

Where #wrap and #twitter-containers are divs that contain the twitter widget. Modify to match your page structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `!important`

```
#activity a:focus {
   color: inherit !important; 
   text-decoration: underline !important;
   outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Valid, but I like to avoid !important unless absolutely necessarily. (If the widget used inline styles, for example.)